# ternary operator is not working in"accept" to get the file format in file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

In the fileupload in jquery i need to upload two types of files.I select the type of file using radio button.

```
 $(".upload-button").fileUpload({
        accept:($('#styleAssetForm').find("input[name='styleType']:checked").val()) ? ".css" : ".otf",
        type: "button"
});
```

I used the ternary operator to get the file format but it is not working.

Comment: What's the HTML? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: yes, but you're just testing if `.val()` returns a non-false-y value. as long as it **HAS** a value that doesn't type-cast/evaluate to false, you'll always get `.css`

Comment: how to check @Marc B

Comment: The problem here is likely that `accept` is only set once, when you first call `fileUpload`. The `.val()` expression is never re-evaluated, and `accept` never changes. It's either `.css` or it's `.otf`, forever, depending on whether or not the box was checked at the time of the `fileUpload` call. I'm not sure the right way to handle it in jQuery File Upload, but you need to dynamically update `accept` either at submission time or whenever the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: And upon reflection, @MarcB is definitely on to something as well, since you've said that `input[name='styleType']` is a *radio* button, rather than a checkbox. In that case, both radio buttons will have a truthy value, unless one has a `value` of the empty string. You'll need to fix both his issue and my issue to get your code working.

Comment: @kalles: `console.log($('#styleAssetForm').find("input[name='styleType']:checked").val())`, basically. simplest workaround is to simply use those two values as the radio buttons' values to begin with, then you don't have use the ternary at all. `accept: $(...).val()`

Answer (score 0):

if your radio button values were:

```
<input type="radio" name="styleType" value=".css"/>
<input type="radio" name="styleType" value=".otf" />
```

then you wouldn't even need a ternary:

```
  $('#styleAssetForm')
        .find("input[name='styleType']:checked")
        .val()
```

That would get you the extension.